# Empty Entry Field on CP

Tags: control-panel

Is there a way to search for entries which do not have content in an `entry` field property on the CP?

I've tried `-field:*` which doesn't return anything, but if I remove this there are entries which have an empty field.

Is there something special to add to get empty `entry` fields?

Comment: Try ``whateverField: ':empty:'``...

Comment: Unfortunately not, does this work for you?

Comment: hm, very strange, for mine this command -fieldSlug:*  is working fine.

Comment: @aodihis Is it an entry field your checking against?

Comment: @JMKelley yes it's an entry field.